# vuejs slot as single file component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

i'm a vue-newbie an trying to achieve the following:

i'm using vue-multiselect (https://vue-multiselect.js.org/) and it supports slots, so i can customize the Options and tags

this works fine and is a really nice feature, but now i will have multiple multiselects in my Project and the templates for the options and tags should be the same. So i thought i could just make a component and use it, but it doesn't work (sure i tried, but with no experience using slots at all)

thats a working Version without components:

```
<vuemultiselect v-model="filter" [...]>
    <template slot="noResult">
        <p v-lang.labels.keineergebnissegefunden></p>
    </template>  
    <template slot="option" slot-scope="props">
        <img v-if="props.option.typ=='person'" src="img/Person.png">
        <img v-else-if="props.option.typ=='article'" src="img/article.png">
        {{props.option.label}}
    </template>
</vuemultiselect>
```

my aproach to separate it:

```
<vuemultiselect v-model="filter" [...]>
    <template slot="noResult">
        <p v-lang.labels.keineergebnissegefunden></p>
    </template>  
    <lw-suche-multiselect-slot-option slot="option" slot-scope="props"></lw-suche-multiselect-slot-option>
</vuemultiselect>
```

the single-file-component (lwSucheMultiselectSlotOption.vue) looks like:

```
<template>
    <div name="option">
        <img v-if="props.option.typ=='person'" src="img/Person.png">
        <img v-else-if="props.option.typ=='article'" src="img/article.png">
        {{props.option.label}}
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    module.exports = {
        created:function()
        {
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
</script>
```

it loads the component, but the props are not there, the browser-console says, that "props" is undefined

does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution!

```
<lw-suche-multiselect-slot-option slot="option" slot-scope="props" :option="props.option"></lw-suche-multiselect-slot-option>
```

component:

```
<template>
    <div>
    [...]
    </div>
</template>
<script>
module.exports = {
    props: ['option'],
    data:function() 
    { 
        return {};
    }
}
</script>
```

ok .. one issue:

the "remove" method doesn't exist because of the scope ... looking for a way to get it working ...

EDIT:

ok this one works for me:

```
<img src="../../img/appbar.delete.png" class="multiselect__tag-icon" @click="remove" style="top:auto;bottom:auto;height:20px; vertical-align:middle">


remove:function()
        {
            this.$parent.removeElement(this.option);
        }
```

seems that everything works now ;)